# How to make irregular div borders

Tags: html, css, rounding

I'm trying to make a div with the top border carved in [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GL9U_GV0cqEtNbreQPCLOqyGfN5oR20h/view?usp=sharing):

Is this possible with CSS?

I've done the top bar with the inverse with radius, but can't figure out how to do this one!

Actual top bar with carved bottom borders:

```css
.hqtopbar {
    background-color: #00519C;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    clip-path: inset(0px 15px 0px 15px);
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: I had my CSS for the top bar. I want to do the same thing at the bottom bar with the top border carved.

Comment: Your link doesn't work. I don't have a one drive account (nor do I want one) and without this it won't work.

Comment: I've change the link to a public Google drive, it should be working now

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, You can do something like this.

```css
.box {
  background: #d89d98;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div> Menu 1 </div>
  <div> Menu 2 </div>
  <div> Menu 3 </div>
</div>
```